# Which property of ClaimsPrincipal can be used to uniquely identify user in a MVC Controller

Tags: azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webapi that is published as a service on Azure. It uses the integrated AD security.

In my Controller, I can get access to the ClaimsPrincipal via the User property. Which of ClaimsPrincipal's properties can be used to uniquely identify the user so that I can use that value to search a SQL table for that users data or store data to a SQL table and include the users unique identification? The identity property has a Name but I was thinking of a more unique identifier.

Or is there a different intended strategy to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`? That should be the actual user id, such as from the PK in the database.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can use either, the **upn** or the **oid** (Object Identifier) claim.

The UPN is typically your login name e. g. yourname@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com whereas the oid is the ObjectId of that user.

**Note:** If you delete and recreate a user with the same email, the upn will be the same whereas the oid will change.

Comment: I've been looking at the different ClaimTypes. I guess that in a given AD, the UPN and NameIdentifier should be unique. Probably either could be used. I think I will need a table of identifiers (AD, Google...) along with an application based PK. I can find the PK through the Authentication services UPN (or whatever it will be called). I don't want to store multiple identifiers with my data. Just a PK mapped to the other identifiers